# Two Publish Events Not working on Single Click in Dojo

Tags: dojo, click, publish-subscribe

Two publishGlobalMessage() events not working at first click on the attach-point mentioned in the code . Publish events are not working on first Click.
The code for the Two publishGlobalMessage() works on the second click only .
Cleared the cache and tried again , but  still not finding the solution.

The Code snippet is as:-

```
on(this._attachpTName", "click", lang.hitch(this.function(){
  this._handleClick("targetpage",{page:hash().split(:)[0]}};

  _handleClick:function(targetPage,props){
  this.publishGlobalMessage("navigate",targetPage,props);

  this.publishGlobalMessage("risk/level/selected",icon.riskLevel);
}
```

Kindly suggest what should be done.

Comment: Please post all your code for your widget as you forgot to include code for publishGlobalMessage

Answer (score 0):

The explicit include of the module in the parent js file helped .
It solved the explicit publish-subscribe problem in the dojo.
Quick fix and this made me solve this problem.